# Loop index in java 8

Tags: loops, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to use streams to write this code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++) {
        if (i % 1000 == 0) {
           doSomething();
        }
        doSomethingElse(list.get(i));
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `doSomethingElse(list.get(i));` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `IntStream` for that... but why should you? It looks basically the same as what you wrote, but has some overhead due to the `IntStream` which is not really needed here.

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
         .forEach(i -> {
           if (i % 1000 == 0) {
             doSomething();
           }
           doSomethingElse(list.get(i));
         });
```

Without knowing what `doSomething` or `doSomethingElse` do, it's hard to make a better proposal. Maybe you want to (or should?) partition your list beforehand?

Comment: You're right. I thought that the code will be less verbose with streams but in this case, there is no need to use theme. Thanks!